# How to make a safe executable?

Tags: java, exe, launch4j

I have been using Launch4j to create an executable based on my code from java. When I run it, windows asks if I really want to run it multiple times, and tries to block the user from running it. Is there anyway I can prevent this? Some sort of certificate I can show windows? I am very new at this, so thanks for all your help.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: I didn't ask that, I want to know if there is anyway I can prevent this from happening or is it not possible? You'll also note that on the page it says "Simply linking here DOES NOT HELP"

Comment: The other point here: your question is also missing an [mcve]. You vaguely describe your problem, leaving out a lot of details. Then you go "any way to prevent that". That really resembles "someone please help me". We can't, given the input we got so far.

Comment: You can replicate this by simply using Launch4j to create any executable then running it on your computer. windows will show the usual "Are you sure you want to run this app?" Although this doesn't show for other executables. I want to know why.

Comment: That very much sounds like a Windows OS thing where the OS doesn't trust that generated binary. And note: this might very well depend on the version of windows and launch4j that you are using. If things were as easy to reproduce as you claim, then for sure this would be a well known problem and thus documented in many places.

Comment: It's not really a problem, just something I would like. I did some more research, and I think it could be solved by just signing the executable anyway. Thanks for your help!